# How do I tell if a pip package was built with C extensions?

Tags: python, pip, pymongo

[Pymongo has some optional C extensions](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/installation.html#dependencies-for-installing-c-extensions-on-unix). If their dependencies are available when pip is run, they get installed; otherwise not.

How do I tell, after the fact, whether the C extensions of a given pip package are present, either at the system level or in a given virtualenv?

While pymongo is my current concern, I'd be happy if a method exists for arbitrary packages.

Comment: What about writing a python script that tries to import them, and exist with error code `1` if it fails, or error code `0` if it succeed? Run it with the virtualenv interpreter to test the virtual env, or the system interpreter to test the system-level import. Or you may even be able to do a one-liner like `python -c "import foob" 2> /dev/null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more elegant solution, but you can first find where the files are located on your machine with pip:

```
vagrant@devboxM:~$ pip show pymongo
---
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: pymongo
Version: 3.2.2
Summary: Python driver for MongoDB <http://www.mongodb.org>
Home-page: http://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver
Author: Bernie Hackett
Author-email: bernie@mongodb.com
Installer: pip
License: Apache License, Version 2.0
Location: /opt/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:
Classifiers:
....
```

You can then go to the directory specifed and see if there are any compiled libraries:

```
vagrant@devboxM:~$ cd /opt/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo
vagrant@devboxM:/opt/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo$ ls
auth.py             database.py                   monitoring.pyc         response.py             ssl_context.pyc
auth.pyc            database.pyc                  monitor.py             response.pyc            ssl_match_hostname.py
bulk.py             errors.py                     monitor.pyc            results.py              ssl_match_hostname.pyc
bulk.pyc            errors.pyc                    monotonic.py           results.pyc             ssl_support.py
client_options.py   helpers.py                    monotonic.pyc          server_description.py   ssl_support.pyc
client_options.pyc  helpers.pyc                   network.py             server_description.pyc  thread_util.py
_cmessage.so        __init__.py                   network.pyc            server.py               thread_util.pyc
collection.py       __init__.pyc                  operations.py          server.pyc              topology_description.py
collection.pyc      ismaster.py                   operations.pyc         server_selectors.py     topology_description.pyc
command_cursor.py   ismaster.pyc                  periodic_executor.py   server_selectors.pyc    topology.py
command_cursor.pyc  message.py                    periodic_executor.pyc  server_type.py          topology.pyc
common.py           message.pyc                   pool.py                server_type.pyc         uri_parser.py
common.pyc          mongo_client.py               pool.pyc               settings.py             uri_parser.pyc
cursor_manager.py   mongo_client.pyc              read_concern.py        settings.pyc            write_concern.py
cursor_manager.pyc  mongo_replica_set_client.py   read_concern.pyc       son_manipulator.py      write_concern.pyc
cursor.py           mongo_replica_set_client.pyc  read_preferences.py    son_manipulator.pyc
cursor.pyc          monitoring.py                 read_preferences.pyc   ssl_context.py
```

If you see a compiled library -- this is a Linux box, so in this case it's `_cmessage.so`, but different platforms have different conventions -- then chances are that it was at least compiled agains *some* of the C extensions.